# C2960 - Memory has insufficient capacity

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, switching

Please, do you know if there is any way on how to release more processor memory from a C2960 switch without restarting it?

I am receiving an insufficient memory alarm from this switch. I noticed that the free memory left is at 10%.

## show memory processor statistics

```
                Head    Total(b)     Used(b)     Free(b)   Lowest(b)  
 Largest(b)
 Processor    2705AEC    22233908    19901044     2332864     1005476     2110036
       I/O    2C00000     4194304     2384652     1809652     1607636     1799784
 Driver te    1880000     1048576          44     1048532     1048532     1048532
```

Comment: What is your software version? Upgrading could potentially solve your problem.

Comment: If there is no other solution then I will check if it can be upgraded. 
     
     Cisco IOS Software, C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASEK9-M), Version 15.0(2)SE11, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)

Comment: Well depending on what type of services you are running on it, the suggested and only other software available for that model is IOS Software 12.2.55-SE12 (MD). This removes functionality though, if you are using some of the available functions in the version 15 software train, then these will not work, when downgrading to version 12. By the way, your switch is end of life and end of service, maybe you should consider replacing it? :-)

Comment: I don't know what type of services they are running on that switch. I work in a NOC team and I have this alarm for insufficient memory and I was trying to see if I can fix it somehow. But since the switch is end of life and end of service, I will just check if we can replace it. Thank you!